# Why the POP() function in condition can really remove the main Func?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have the following code, given a string s containing just the characters '(', ')', '{', '}', '[' and ']', and return True or False if

1. Open brackets must be closed by the same type of brackets.
2. Open brackets must be closed in the correct order.
3. Every close bracket has a corresponding open bracket of the same type.

```
def isValid(s):
    stack = []

    open_bracket = ['(', '{', '[']
    close_bracket = [')', '}', ']']

    for i in s:
        if i in open_bracket:
            stack.append(i)
        if i in close_bracket:
            if stack == [] or close_bracket.index(i) != open_bracket.index(stack. Pop()):

                return False
    return (True if stack == [] else False)
```

Here is a question when I practice Leetcode.

Why the function use `stack.Pop()` in condition influence the `list_stack`?

```
 if stack == [] or close_bracket.index(i) != open_bracket.index(stack. Pop())
```

I can't get the picture. Why does it really remove the last item in stack?

The code comes from https://leetcode.com/problems/valid-parentheses/discuss/2601510/Python-Using-Stack-and-Index

Comment: Are you asking why `list.pop()` modifies the list, or why this solution is using `pop` in the first place?

Comment: I'm confused it use pop in if condition, but  modifies the list...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Why the function use `stack.Pop()` in condition influence the list `stack`?*

```
if stack == [] or close_bracket.index(i) != open_bracket.index(stack. Pop())
```

*I can't get the picture. Why does it really remove the last item in stack?*

In Python expressions are evaluated from left to the right and logical conditions are only evaluated up to the value which is able to determine the final outcome.

In case of logical `or` if `stack == []` would evaluate to `True` no further terms would be evaluated. If it evaluates to `False` there is at least one item in the list and the next term in `or` will be evaluated removing one item from the stack list in order to calculate one of the values which is needed for evaluation of the `!=` condition.

The `.pop()` method works in-place on the list removing the last item from it and providing it as a return value. So the `stack` will be modified by `.pop()`, but this modification won't influence the outcome of boolean test on first term in `or` in case the `stack` becomes in this process an empty list because this term was already evaluated before and won't be evaluated again.

*Why `.pop()`?*. It is necessary to remove from `stack` the entry about an opening bracket in case a matching closing bracket is detected. This makes sure that all the opening brackets are removed from `stack` if there is an appropriate sequence of closing brackets.